# Untrack file without deleting it?

Tags: magit, git

I have a tracked file in a git repository. How do I untrack this file without deleting it using magit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hitting `i` will gitignore the file and untrack it from the git repository.

Behind the scenes, it does `git rm --cached` - [More info about this git command from a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936249/1219634)

Comment: Note that you don't need to add it to the gitignore file. Just discard(I believe by default "k") changes on gitignore after i.

Comment: Discarding (using `k`) just reverts the file contents to its last committed state; it does not untrack it. To test it, modify the file you just discarded, hit `g` in the magit buffer to refresh the contents and you will see that file appear once again in the *Unstaged* section.

Comment: I mean discarding the changes on .gitignore.

Comment: Alright, I now get what you are saying. First hit `i` on the file you want to untrack and then hit `k` on `.gitignore`. For my use case, if there's a file I want to untrack, I usually want to gitignore it too. That way my magit buffer stays clean and empty :)

Comment: If you don't need to add the file to gitignore, use K (that's uppercase k).

Comment: Where do you view the files in the first place?

Comment: @young_souvlaki In the Magit status buffer.

Comment: @KaushalModi My status buffer shows only untracked files when there are no changes.

Answer (score 23):

In the Magit buffer, hit K (uppercase k) on the file. It works with magit 2.3; I don't know for earlier versions.

Comment: [f6a6f40fe8321f3ceb4b8ea9581e450149fea66a](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/f6a6f40fe8321f3ceb4b8ea9581e450149fea66a), looks like it's since 2.1

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer for the question asked, even though the others were helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Use `M-x magit-file-untrack` from a buffer visiting a tracked file or from a Magit buffer. When the buffer visits a file then that file is offered as default choice.

When point is on a file in a Magit buffer, then that is also offered as default. You might also want to add the new `magit-insert-tracked-files` to `magit-status-sections-hook`, then a tree of all tracked files is inserted into the status buffer (but doing so might not be good for performance in big repositories).

Comment: In spacemacs this is bound to `X`.