# Git rm from magit

Tags: magit, deletion

This is a very basic but I have been unable to find the answer on the web.
Is it possible to `git rm`, i.e. to remove a tracked file, from magit?

Thanks

Comment: The question has been asked and answered on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/516639/what-is-an-equivalent-of-git-rm-r-in-the-emacs-magit-package.

Comment: There is also magit-do-async-shell-command, which I have bound to "&" in a magit-status buffer.

Answer (score 35):

Magit does not provide a command that does `git rm` (but if you opened a feature request, then I would probably add it eventually).

Meanwhile you can delete the file using some other method, e.g. using <kbd>M-x delete-file RET <file> RET</kbd>. Once you have done that refresh the Magit buffer using <kbd>g</kbd> and then stage the "deletion" of the file by moving to it in the list of unstaged changes and then pressing <kbd>s</kbd>.

Answer (score 22):

Magit doesn't support `git rm`. Instead, delete the folder in dired, and then stage the change.

You can also use <kbd>!</kbd> to launch any git command.

Comment: `K` (`magit-file-untrack`) does `git rm --cached`

Comment: This 'K' key is very usefull. Thanks.

Comment: @npostavs Why isn't your comment the accepted answer?

Comment: @Daniel It's an answer [for a different question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/untrack-file-without-deleting-it).

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for the comment. I see, so `git rm --cached` does not remove the file from disk, whereas `git rm` does. Thanks!

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks